# TypeScript: functional interface with constructor

Tags: typescript

I want a class that behaves like js Date function:

1. when called via `new` it creates an instance of class.
2. when called as a function it does some static stuff.

How do i implement this interface?

```
interface A {
    (): string;
    new(arg: number);
    GetValue(): number;
}
```

current solution that doesn't compile but produces correct js code in playground:

```
class B implements A {

    private Value: number;

    constructor(arg: number) {
        if (this.constructor == B) {
            this.Value = arg;
        } else {
            return "42";
        } 
    }

    GetValue(): number {
        return this.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an [ES2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) or [later](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) `class` to let you call a constructor without the `new` keyword.  In Step 2 of Section 9.2.1 of the linked documents, calling a class constructor without the `new` keyword should result in a `TypeError` being thrown.  (If you target ES5 in TypeScript you'll get something that works at runtime, but if you target ES2015 or above you will get runtime errors.  It's best not to do this.)  So to implement your interface you will need to use a pre-ES2015 constructor function instead.

---

By the way, the `new(arg: number)` signature needs a return type.  For example:

```
interface A {
  (): string;
  new(arg: number): AInstance; // return something
  GetValue(): number;
}
// define the instance type
interface AInstance { 
  instanceMethod(): void;
}
```

---

Here's one way to implement that.  First, make a `class` for `AInstance`:

```
class _A implements AInstance {
  constructor(arg: number) { } // implement
  instanceMethod() { } // implement
}
```

Then, make a function that can be called with or without `new`:

```
const AFunctionLike =
  function(arg?: number): AInstance | string {
    if (typeof arg !== "undefined") {
      return new _A(arg);
    }
    return "string";
  } as { new(arg: number): AInstance, (): string };
```

I've decided that if you call `AFunctionLike` with an argument then you will get an `AInstance`, otherwise you will get a `string`.  You can also check explicitly for whether `new` was used, via [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target), if your runtime has support for it.

Also note that I had to assert that `AFunctionLike` is newable (with the `as` clause on the last line) since there's currently no other way to tell TypeScript that a standalone function can be called with `new`.

Now we're almost done.  We can declare a value of type `A` as follows:

```
const A: A = Object.assign(
  AFunctionLike,
  {
    GetValue() {
      return 1;
    }
  }
);
```

The value `A` has been formed by merging `AFunctionLike` with an object that implements `GetValue()`.  You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals) to do this merging.

---

That's it.  You can verify that this works at runtime [on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%28%29%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20new%28arg%3A%20number%29%3A%20AInstance%3B%0D%0A%20%20GetValue%28%29%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20AInstance%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20instanceMethod%28%29%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20_A%20implements%20AInstance%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor%28arg%3A%20number%29%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20instanceMethod%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20AFunctionLike%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20function%28arg%3F%3A%20number%29%3A%20AInstance%20%7C%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28typeof%20arg%20%21%3D%3D%20%22undefined%22%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20_A%28arg%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22string%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20as%20%7B%20new%28arg%3A%20number%29%3A%20AInstance%2C%20%28%29%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20A%3A%20A%20%3D%20Object.assign%28%0D%0A%20%20AFunctionLike%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GetValue%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%29%3B%0D%0A).  Good luck!