# TypeScript interface signature "(): string"

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, typescript, interface

In types definitions from a standard Node.js library, I found a definition of the interface `DateConstructor`.

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new(): Date;
    new(value: number): Date;
    new(value: string): Date;
    new(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
    (): string;
    readonly prototype: Date;
    /**
      * Parses a string containing a date, and returns the number of milliseconds between that date and midnight, January 1, 1970.
      * @param s A date string
      */
    parse(s: string): number;
    /**
      * Returns the number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970 Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) (or GMT) and the specified date.
      * @param year The full year designation is required for cross-century date accuracy. If year is between 0 and 99 is used, then year is assumed to be 1900 + year.
      * @param month The month as an number between 0 and 11 (January to December).
      * @param date The date as an number between 1 and 31.
      * @param hours Must be supplied if minutes is supplied. An number from 0 to 23 (midnight to 11pm) that specifies the hour.
      * @param minutes Must be supplied if seconds is supplied. An number from 0 to 59 that specifies the minutes.
      * @param seconds Must be supplied if milliseconds is supplied. An number from 0 to 59 that specifies the seconds.
      * @param ms An number from 0 to 999 that specifies the milliseconds.
      */
    UTC(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): number;
    now(): number;
}

declare const Date: DateConstructor;
```

It contains strange definition `(): string`. How can I define it in class, that wants to implement this interface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: functional interface with constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809986/typescript-functional-interface-with-constructor/46812163#46812163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you think this question is different enough from [the other one I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809986/typescript-functional-interface-with-constructor/46812163#46812163):

That definition means the class constructor is also a callable function with no arguments that returns a string when called without `new`.  You can't use a [ES2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)-or-[later](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) `class` and adhere to the specification, since it would need to throw a `TypeError` upon being called without `new`.  Instead you can return a function that detects being called with `new`, with extra properties added to implement static methods.

I'll give you an example where I provide a wrapper around the built-in `Date` constructor object.  First let's describe the part of the interface that acts like a function, either with or without the `new` keyword:

```
interface FunctionalPartOfDateConstructor {
  new(): Date;
  new(value: number): Date;
  new(value: string): Date;
  new(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
  (): string;
}
```

Now let's try to implement just that part:

```
const funcPart = function(valueOrYear?: number | string, month?: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date | string {
  if (typeof new.target === 'undefined') {
    // called as function
    return Date();
  }
  if (typeof valueOrYear === 'undefined') {
    // called as constructor with no arguments
    return new Date();
  }
  if (typeof valueOrYear === 'string') {
    // called as constructor with string value argument
    return new Date(valueOrYear);
  }
  if (typeof month === 'undefined') {
    // called as constructor with number value argument
    return new Date(valueOrYear);
  }
  // called as constructor with year, month, date, etc arguments:
  return new Date(valueOrYear, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms);
} as FunctionalPartOfDateConstructor;
```

Note that I use [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) to detect if the function is called with `new`.  This compiles to something reasonable when targeting ES5, I think.  And note that it has to tease apart the difference between all the different overload signatures.

Now we can make the full `DateConstructor` instance by merging the functional part with something that implements static methods:

```
const myDateConstructor: DateConstructor = Object.assign(funcPart, {
  prototype: Date.prototype,
  parse(s: string) {
    return Date.parse(s);
  },
  UTC(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number) {
    return Date.UTC(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms);
  },
  now() {
    return Date.now();
  }
})
```

You can [try it on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=interface%20FunctionalPartOfDateConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%28%29%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%20%20new%28value%3A%20number%29%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%20%20new%28value%3A%20string%29%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%20%20new%28year%3A%20number%2C%20month%3A%20number%2C%20date%3F%3A%20number%2C%20hours%3F%3A%20number%2C%20minutes%3F%3A%20number%2C%20seconds%3F%3A%20number%2C%20ms%3F%3A%20number%29%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%20%20%28%29%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20funcPart%20%3D%20function%28valueOrYear%3F%3A%20number%20%7C%20string%2C%20month%3F%3A%20number%2C%20date%3F%3A%20number%2C%20hours%3F%3A%20number%2C%20minutes%3F%3A%20number%2C%20seconds%3F%3A%20number%2C%20ms%3F%3A%20number%29%3A%20Date%20%7C%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20%28typeof%20new.target%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27undefined%27%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20called%20as%20function%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Date%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20if%20%28typeof%20valueOrYear%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27undefined%27%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20called%20as%20constructor%20with%20no%20arguments%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Date%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20if%20%28typeof%20valueOrYear%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27string%27%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20called%20as%20constructor%20with%20string%20value%20argument%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Date%28valueOrYear%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20if%20%28typeof%20month%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27undefined%27%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20called%20as%20constructor%20with%20number%20value%20argument%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Date%28valueOrYear%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20called%20as%20constructor%20with%20year%2C%20month%2C%20date%2C%20etc%20arguments%3A%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Date%28valueOrYear%2C%20month%2C%20date%2C%20hours%2C%20minutes%2C%20seconds%2C%20ms%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%20as%20FunctionalPartOfDateConstructor%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myDateConstructor%3A%20DateConstructor%20%3D%20Object.assign%28funcPart%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20prototype%3A%20Date.prototype%2C%0D%0A%20%20parse%28s%3A%20string%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Date.parse%28s%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20UTC%28year%3A%20number%2C%20month%3A%20number%2C%20date%3F%3A%20number%2C%20hours%3F%3A%20number%2C%20minutes%3F%3A%20number%2C%20seconds%3F%3A%20number%2C%20ms%3F%3A%20number%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Date.UTC%28year%2C%20month%2C%20date%2C%20hours%2C%20minutes%2C%20seconds%2C%20ms%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20now%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Date.now%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%29%0D%0A) if you want.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you. It very helps me.